# How to add css class?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Screen.Description)
```

How to add a class or some other attributes to the generated input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in editor template is too generic (it can display arbitrary objects) for such a concept to make sense. You could either

1. [Write your own editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html)
2. If it's only a single property you're displaying you could use a more specific helper method such as [`Html.TextBoxFor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703535.aspx):

   ```
   @Html.TextBoxForm(m => m.Screen.Description, new { @class = "myClass" })
   ```